# How can you override an enum in C#?

Tags: c#, enums, overloading

This is my code:

```
void Main()
{
    StarTrek baseClass = new StarTrek();
    NewGeneration childClass = new NewGeneration();

    baseClass.ShowEnum();
    childClass.ShowEnum();
}

public class StarTrek
{
    internal enum Characters
    {
        Kirk, Spock, Sulu, Scott
    }

    public void ShowEnum()
    {
        Type reflectedEnum = typeof(Characters);
        IEnumerable<string> members = reflectedEnum.GetFields()
                                            .ToList()
                                            .Where(item => item.IsSpecialName == false)
                                            .Select(item => item.Name);
        string.Join(", ", members).Dump();
    }
}

public class NewGeneration : StarTrek
{
    internal new enum Characters
    {
        Picard, Riker, Worf, Geordi
    }       
}
```

ShowEnum always displays:

> Kirk, Spock, Sulu, Scott

even if it was called in the NewGeneration class. Am I missing/misunderstanding something?  Is there a way for ShowEnum to use the NewGeneration.Characters instead of StarTrek.Characters?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your second enum is *shadowing* the first one, in just the same way as declaring a new field within `NewGeneration` would. Nested types aren't polymorphic - the code in `ShowEnum` will *always* refer to `StarTrek.Characters`; the code is built against that type at compile-time.

It's not really clear what you're trying to do, but you definitely can't do it in the way that you're trying. If you want polymorphic behaviour you *have* to be using methods, properties or events, which must then be declared virtual in order to be overridden in the derived class.

(It's worth noting that overloading and overriding are different, by the way - your question refers to overloading but I think you meant overriding.)

Comment: I thought by hiding the original enum, ShowEnum would display the overridden enum.  I've clarified my question.

Comment: I have found another way to get the "overridden" enum using reflection.  It's ugly and a hack and I don't want to post it in fear of online ridicule :)

Answer (score 2):

You can't overload `enum`s - they are not classes or structs.

With `internal new` you are simply *hiding* the original property, though, since you are  `ShowEnum` is defined on the base class, the base class implementation of the property is called.

Answer (score 1):

```
public class StarTrek
{
    internal virtual IList<string> Characters
    {
        get
        {
            return new List<string> { Kirk, Spock, Sulu, Scott };
        }
    }

    public void ShowEnum()
    {
        string.Join(", ", Characters).Dump();
    }
}

public class NewGeneration : StarTrek
{
    internal override IList<string> Characters
    {
        get
        {
            return new List<string> { Picard, Riker, Worf, Geordi };
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not really after the output, what I really want is how to "override" enums in the child class.

Comment: like the others said you can't

Answer (score 1):

```
class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        StarTrek baseClass = new StarTrek();
        NewGeneration childClass = new NewGeneration();

        baseClass.ShowEnum();
        childClass.ShowEnum();
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}


public class StarTrek
{
    internal enum Characters
    {
        Kirk, Spock, Sulu, Scott
    }

    public virtual void ShowEnum()
    {
        Type reflectedEnum = typeof(Characters);
        IEnumerable<string> members = reflectedEnum.GetFields()
                                            .ToList()
                                            .Where(item => item.IsSpecialName == false)
                                            .Select(item => item.Name);
        Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", members.ToArray()));
    }
}

public class NewGeneration : StarTrek
{
    internal new enum Characters
    {
        Picard, Riker, Worf, Geordi
    }

    public override void ShowEnum()
    {
        Type reflectedEnum = typeof(Characters);
        IEnumerable<string> members = reflectedEnum.GetFields()
                                            .ToList()
                                            .Where(item => item.IsSpecialName == false)
                                            .Select(item => item.Name);
        Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", members.ToArray()));

    }
}
```